# how to view all pods of a particular service in a particular namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

So, if we use

```
kubectl get pods -n namespace.
```

we can easily view all pods in a particular namespaces.

my question is how can i view pods in a particular namespace which is associated with a particular service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *selector* corresponding to the *selector* that you have declared in your `Service`

E.g.

```
kubectl get pods --selector=app=cassandra
```

corresponds to this example `Service`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cassandra-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: cassandra

# more lines
```

Comment: what if any label not mention. ?

Comment: If there are no labels then how does the service distribute traffic to its pods?

Comment: is it possible there would be different labels and we can use one service for all.